# "Invalid access to memory location" error on IIS server

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

Last night we rebooted several of our windows servers (virtual environment) to install security patches.  After doing so we started to receive a `Invalid access to memory location` error on all of the websites on one of our web servers. It is a windows 2003 server. This was only one of the many web servers rebooted and only this one had the problem.

We restored the server back to a point in time before the security patches were installed. We are still getting the same error. This is leading us to believe that it was something that was changed some time ago, but took affect when the server was rebooted and has nothing to do with the security patches.

I tried creating a new IIS website with a new app pool and just put a "test.html" file in the new website and I received the same error, so it is not any of our application code, it is something at the server or iis service level.

Any ideas what I might be able to try to fix this problem?

Comment: It might be related to invalid or missing system environment variables for .dll files.Here are a couple of links that may help: http://forums.asp.net/t/950585.aspx  http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10341140-RESOLVED-Invalid-access-to-memory-location

Comment: Have you looked in the Event logs to try and glean some clues?

Comment: It turns out that IIS was trying to start coldfusion, which is no longer used on that server. We took the reference to coldfusion out and it worked properly.